# Cocos2d - Combine CCSequence and Bool! is it possible

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to ask is it possible to combine ccsequence and a bool??

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                 myAnimation,
                 (myBool = YES),
                 [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:myTime],
                 [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(otherAnimation)],
                 nil]];
```

But if i do it this way the program breaks down.

Does anybody know a solution??

Answer (score 2):

you was on the right way, you can simply change your action like this

```
[self runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                 myAnimation,
                 //OLD_VERSION(myBool = YES), 
                 [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(yourBoolMethod)], 
                 [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:myTime],
                 [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(otherAnimation)],
                 nil]];
```

and inside `yourBoolMethod` set the bool as true

```
-(void) yourBoolMethod {
      myBool = YES:
}
```